# open music file from raw folder to play on default app of the device using an intent on android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to write  an intent to open the default music player of the device to play a music file (mp3) I have on raw folder in my android studio project . thus far I found the code for the intent but I got stack on how to order it to open the specific mp3 file an dplay it on the media player so far I have wrote something like this trying to find te uri also of the file but I cant put them together on how should I do it the file name of the mp3 is "greeceMusic" if it helps at all. the code I have so far is

`@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

```
            Intent musicIntent = new Intent();

            //use Action VIEW to launch app

            musicIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            File file = new File("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.greeceMusic);

            musicIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");

            startActivity(musicIntent);
        }`
```

any help would be gratly appreciated as for I'm really new at this and I need all the help I can get cause when I found a similar post in the forum it don't help me a lot cause I couldn't put together the instructions  thanks in advance

Comment: you can extract your raw resource in the device memory, and play it after words.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.greeceMusic);
```

First, a resource is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device.

Second, you cannot use a `Uri` syntax with a scheme, like `android.resource://`, with `File`.

Third, do not use wildcard MIME types when creating an `Intent` like this. You know what the actual MIME type is, as you are the one packaging the media into your app.  So, use the actual MIME type.

Fourth, even if you correctly created the `Uri` (e.g., `Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.greeceMusic)`), it is unlikely that many devices will have an app capable of playing a music file published in the form of a raw resource.

Your best option is to copy the resource contents to a file (e.g., `openRawResource()` on `Resources`, then copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to a `FileOutputStream`), then try to play the file (e.g., served via a `FileProvider`).